# Laravel 5 Post-login actions/hooks

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, I want to add some custom user-specific data to a session variable after the user has logged in. I understand there may be a way to do this by overriding postLogin() in the Authentication controller, however I think there may also be a way to do it using Middleware?

However, I am not sure where I would place the Middleware so that it is executed straight after authentication has succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place it in Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
if ($this->auth->check())
{
    //place your code here

    return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
}
```

Comment: I ended up placing it in the "Authenticate.php" middleware, as RedirectIfAuthenticated only seems to run if the user tries to reach the login page after already logging in